# Android i-jetty server access over 3g

Tags: java, android, jetty

With an android app that uses an `i-jetty` server, I managed to connect to an android device from a PC web browser over wifi. However, I want to enable connecting over a 3g (mobile data) network. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Most mobile carriers issue private IP addresses to devices. These are not accessible by anything else other than perhaps other devices on that carrier's network. This is not significantly different from running a Web server on a home PC.

Comment: How then work app like airdroid?

Comment: Presumably, the clients don't communicate with the device. They communicate with an AirDroid-hosted server farm, which communicates with the device (using GCM, WebSockets, or some sort of push mechanism).